# How do I get my built-in wireless adapter to work?

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, hp

Recently I have decided to start looking into Linux, and specifically I have decided on Ubuntu, which I first set up this past Saturday.

After about a day, my wifi cut out unexpectedly, and I was unable to connect to, or find, any networks nearby. This was accompanied by a notification saying something like "Network connection failed".

For some reason, after about a minute of internet access when I restart, the wifi cuts out with the same message every time. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me figure out how to fix this issue.

I'm fairly new to heavy use of the terminal too, but here's the lspci information if that helps out at all. My laptop is an HP Pavilion.

```
anashi@Lumos:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation BayHubTech Integrated SD controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9da8 (rev 30)
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dab (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter (rev ff)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black 2018/PC SN520 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
```

Comment: Further information should NOT be added in comments, but should be added by editing ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1248940/edit ) your Question, and making use of the formatting tools.

Comment: Look at the log files, and post a subset: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`. Also, run `https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info`